# Center and Stretch on a Standard WinForms Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

So, doing what I'm attempting to do is trivial in WPF, but in WinForms it seems to be a bit problematic:

When using a TableLayoutPanel, you can simply set the Anchor properties to NONE to center the control within the cell of the TableLayoutPanel and then set `Anchor.Right | Anchor.Left` flags on the control to stretch it to the size of the cell.  This behavior does not seem to work properly when using a standard WinForms `Panel` container.  When setting the Anchor property on the child control (`TextBox`) within the `Panel` the control does not appear to stretch out, nor center itself within the container.

I've looked up some other answers regarding similar issues to this, but I feel like I'm missing something here.  Most of them say just use the Anchor property, but that doesn't not appear to work.  Does this need to be manually calculated on load (and each resize), or can the Anchor property actually assist me with this?

Comment: Anchor works fine for stretching; to center you simply center it before. To center without resizing you indeed have to calculate yourself.

Comment: So sounds like I need to do some math to keep the components centered. on the resize event.  I had a feeling this was the case, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: Yup; you may want to write a function.. Also think about nesting Controls that should stay together in another Panel

Comment: Thanks.  I actually am nesting the controls in this panel container.  The underlying issue here is that the ErrorProvider control does not work properly in a `TableLayoutPanel` which makes up the main layout of the UserControl, so I need to use a regular Panel to have the ErrorProvider actually show up in the parent of the invalid control.

Comment: _ErrorProvider control does not work properly in a TableLayoutPanel_  Curious: What problem do you have with it?

Comment: The errorprovider does not always display properly when the controls' parent is a TableLayoutPanel.  This is the case when there is not an extra column adjacent to the control that failed validation since you cannot have more than one control in a cell.

Comment: You could set the right Padding to, say 12.

Comment: @TaW I wish it was that easy! The error provider still won't show up unless you make an adjacent column that's large enough to display the errorprovider.  I've tried a bunch of different ways so far.  It seems like the easiest method is to embed the control into a panel within the cell and just programmatically center it.

Comment: Not here. I set the TableLayoutPanel.Pading.Right to 12 and it shows. Anthing less and it gets cut off more and more until it disappears. You lose 12 pixels to the right, but that's easier than creating a dummy column. The Control (a TextBox) in the Cell is docked to Fill.

Comment: Hmm...maybe I need to some more testing.  I had issues when using padding/margins however, I'm not docking the controls, only anchoring them.

Comment: That should work as well. Margins don't do a lot unless in a FlowLayoutPanel I believe. Do you have CellBorder styles?

Comment: We should move this to chat...but no I'm not using CellBorder styles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57764/discussion-between-taw-and-jnyranger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a Control centered works automatically only if you combine stretching it with Anchors.
If you want it centered without stretching it you'll have to do a *little* bit of math in the Resize event:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourControl.Left = (yourControl.Parent.ClientSize.Width - yourControl.Width) / 2; 
}
```

For centering vertically the same rules apply.

With regard to the disappearing ErrorProvider: The ErrorProviders need a little space, on my machine 12 pixels will do. To provide that space for the rightmost cells in an TableLayoutPanel you can set its padding like this:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 12, 0);
```

Note how this nicely adds the padding between the Cellborders, if you have any, and the outside.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms171688(v=vs.110).aspx) has a page dedicated to this already. (although this mentioned a button, the idea remains the same)

Comment: I am trying to mimic this behavior in a standard Panel, NOT a TableLayoutPanel.  This is stated in my question.